# Energy Per Dry Ice Mass Required By de Laval Expansion of Air?

Tags: thermodynamics, physical-chemistry, climate-science, gas

There has been a lot of talk lately about CO2 extraction from air.  Since there are rocket engines in which ice crystals precipitate in the exhaust when expanding into near vacuum, it seems dry ice may condense out of air by suitable expansion, into atmospheric pressure, through a de Lavel nozzle, after cooling the compressed air to ambient temperature.

This is likely to be very energy inefficient compared to more capital intensive processes, but my question is exactly how inefficient is it?  That is to say, how much energy does such a simple system require to extract a given mass of CO2, as dry ice precipitate from air at, say STP with 400ppm CO2?